# NextJS huge icon on initial page load after build project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I have some problem with icons and style were used in NextJs. I use material-ui in my project, developed time everything is ok but when i build project, the icons first be large then it gets normal. I try used other icon sets but result isn't change. Is it a NextJs bug?.

Before :
[image]

After :
[image]

Comment: How long does it take ? It seems like your CSS doesnt load entirely at first. I guess your icons are resized to be smaller than their original size ?

Comment: Yes I agree with you, about one second

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `width` property to set the icon default size, so when the CSS completely loads, they change to the icon's size.

```js
<Icon width="16" />
```

Comment: This issue isn't just about icons, it's also about post-loading of css files. I guess I need to solve this

Answer (score 1):

This seem to help me with MUI icons

Before:

```
<WebAssetOffIcon sx={{maxWidth: 60, maxHeight: 60 }} />
```

After:

```
<WebAssetOffIcon style={{ maxWidth: 60, maxHeight: 60 }} />
```

Somone mentioned:
"The cause is the fact that the icon is being rendered before the CSS is loaded."

Answer (score 0):

add below code to your app.js/ts file it should fix your problem

```
import { config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' // 
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css' // 
config.autoAddCss = false //
```

credit goes https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/issues/234

Answer (score -1):

Please add this code to "_document.js"
_document.js

```
import Document, {Html, Head, NextScript, Main} from 'next/document'
import {ServerStyleSheet} from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({renderPage}) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const page = renderPage(App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props}/>));
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleElement();
    return {...page, styleTags};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head/>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript/>
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

~ Storm In Talent